# How can I accelerate an already moving object?

Tags: javascript

I am working on learning a new coding language, which in Javascript in this. We are starting simple: Creating a rectangle making it move horizontally over the screen. However I need to find a way to make it speed up the longer it goes on.

So far the only thing I could figure out and find out is that I could use the existing value and multiply it by a very small factor that is slightly higher than one ('IF' statement). However, is there a different and easier way to do this?

```
//variabelen X en Y

var posX;
var posY;


//Canvas
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    posX = 0;
    posY = 50;

}

//rode vierkant

function draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(posX, posY, 50, 50);
    posX = posX + 1;

    if (posX >= 1) { 

        posX = posX * 1.05;
    }

}
```

As mentioned above, I expect the red rectangle to start with a certain speed (in this case +1) and then gradually accelerate.

Comment: You'll need to keep two variables called `velX, velY` too for the velocity.

Comment: This seems like more a maths question. Is there a problem with your current approach? At first glance it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Why? Its Y-velocity is always zero.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit one could say the same for `posY`, but OP has included it anyway (probably for future changes).

Comment: Given a constant acceleration *a*, the position along an axis will turn out to follow a quadratic formula: x = 0.5*a*t^2 + v0*t + x0. This is really a physics problem.

Comment: @vorkot1 your current approach should work fine as per your description, but keep in mind the object will accelerate **very** quickly, possibly disappearing off the edge of the screen before you can react.

Comment: @vorkot1 you've probably been searching for the wrong thing; there are tons of tutorials on equations of motion. As I said, keep variables `velX, velY`, increment them by the acceleration, and increment `posX, posY` by them.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog It still needs a Y position, it just doesn't change.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm just saying OP could have just written `rect(posX, 50, 50, 50);`, but they left `posY` in there which suggests they might want to modify its behavior later on. I don't understand why this has become a subject of discussion.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Well when you make a suggestion here it is subject to peer review for accuracy and relevance - that's what you open yourself up to on SO - it's  a good thing :) You claimed "you'll **need** to keep two variables for the velocity" (emphasis mine) and I'm simply pointing out that this is not true. Have a good one.

Comment: @vorkot1 ah I see it was simply a variable offset; in that case yes you only need `velX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to declare another variable to keep track of the velocity.
Then, in each iteration of the draw loop, increase that velocity by a certain amount:

```js
var posX;
var posY;
var vel;


//Canvas
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    posX = 0;
    posY = 50;
    vel = 1;
}

//rode vierkant

function draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(posX, posY, 50, 50);
    posX += vel;
    vel *= 1.05;
}
```

Comment: You should explain your solution rather than simply dumping code